# TextWatcher for more than one EditText

Tags: android, interface, android-activity, android-edittext, textwatcher

I want to implement the `TextWatcher` interface for more than one `EditText` fields. Currently I am using :

```
text1.addTextChangedListener(this);
text2.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

then overriding the methods in my Activity:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
 // do some operation on text of text1 field
 // do some operation on text of text2 field 
}
```

However this is working fine but I'm looking for other ways so that I can explicitly identify that in which `EditText` field the `SoftKeyboard` is currently focused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Single TextWatcher for multiple EditTexts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702771/how-to-use-single-textwatcher-for-multiple-edittexts)

Comment: @SkyKelsey The answer you wrote is actually creating multiple instances of TextWatcher, therefore I think that is not the perfect answer for what has been asked by OP, regarding my question is about identifying the each EditText in a TextWatcher interface methods.

Comment: https://github.com/henrychuangtw/AutoInsertEditText

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Suggested solution in [@Sebastian Roth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4283532/779408) is not one instance of `TextWatcher` for some `EditTexts`. It is one class and n instances of that class for n `EditTexts`.

Each EditText has its own Spannable. `TextWatcher`'s events has this Spannable as `s` parameter. I check their hashCode (unique Id of each object). myEditText1.getText() returns that Spannable. So if the `myEditText1.getText().hashCode()` equals with `s.hashCode()` it means that `s` belongs to `myEditText1`

So if you want to have one instance of `TextWatcher` for some `EditTexts` you should use this:

```
private TextWatcher generalTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {    

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

        if (myEditText1.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
        {
            myEditText1_onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
        }
        else if (myEditText2.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
        {
            myEditText2_onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

        if (myEditText1.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
        {
            myEditText1_beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after);
        }
        else if (myEditText2.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
        {
            myEditText2_beforeTextChanged(s, start, count, after);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (myEditText1.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
        {
            myEditText1_afterTextChanged(s);
        }
        else if (myEditText2.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode())
        {
            myEditText2_afterTextChanged(s);
        }
    }

};
```

and

```
myEditText1.addTextChangedListener(generalTextWatcher);
myEditText2.addTextChangedListener(generalTextWatcher);
```

Comment: Have you double checked this solution? What happens if a user enters the same text in both input fields?

Comment: @SebastianRoth Each EditText has its own Spannable. `TextWatcher` events has this Spannable as `CharSequence` or `Editable` parameters. I do not check the Text value of EditTexts. I check their hashCode (unique Id of each object). `myEditText1.getText()` returns that `Spannable` not the Text value. So if the `myEditText1.getText().hashCode()` equals with `s.hashCode()` means that s belongs to `myEditText1`

Comment: Your opening paragraph is confusing - at least it confused me. "Suggested solution is ... ". I thought you were saying that is what you were suggesting.

Comment: @RenniePet I mean Sebastian Roth's answer

Comment: OK, thanks for the edit. But now I have another question. (I'm fairly new to Android and Java, so please bear with me.) I don't understand why you are involving the hashCode() method to test if the spannable objects are the same objects or not. Why not just compare them with "=="? (In C# I'd use ObjectEquals(), but in Java one just uses ==, right?)

Comment: This is a bad solution. As soon as you have two EditTexts with the same string it will fail as it will be the same string (therefore the same hashcode) in memory.

Comment: @Amorgos `myEditText1.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()` does not check the content of the Editable. I check the Editable objects which is different for each EditText and same for every content

Comment: Are you sure all hashes are unique? What about hash collisions?

Comment: @breceivemail, what is required to do in methods you are calling in all if else statements? e.g. `myEditText1_onTextChanged(s, start, before, count);` and others more. I am implementing one textwatcher instance and i want to use it for multiple edittext which they all share same input.

Comment: So far best solution.

Comment: It's just bad and inconsistent library design. I mean why doesn't the `onTextChanged` also pass the sender object same as `onFocusChange`?! That would make everything a lot easier.

Answer (score 89):

I would do it like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    EditText e = new EditText(this);
    e.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(e));
}

private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e) { 
        mEditText = e;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea, but this means that you have a separate text watcher for each EditText.

Comment: this answer is not `Single TextWatcher for multiple EditTexts`. It is 3 instances of one TextWatcher class. So 3 separate TextWatchers are controlling 3 EditTexts.

Comment: @breceivemail, one class, 3 instances. Agreed it's hard when people don't specify their object type. His objective was to write the code only once, so there it is.

Comment: What's so custom about this ? I don't get it

Comment: @Bobs, I suppose it is easier to make 3 objects instead of writing one difficult and support it's future changes.

Answer (score 15):

I use this solution:

- Add method that returns listener:

  ```
  private TextWatcher getTextWatcher(final EditText editText) {
      return new TextWatcher() {
          @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
              // do what you want with your EditText
              editText.setText("blabla");
          }

          @Override
          public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

          }
      };
  }
  ```
- Add listener to multiple EditText's, you can also pass other parameters:

  ```
  editText1.addTextChangedListener(getTextWatcher(editText1));
  editText2.addTextChangedListener(getTextWatcher(editText2));
  editText3.addTextChangedListener(getTextWatcher(editText3));
  ```

Comment: Best ever ans ... nothing to change in code .  thanks u so much

Comment: Simple and hence the "Best Answer"

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 12):

using "CustomTextWatcher" idea, I done that

1) Crated a new TextWatcherListener interface:

```
public interface TextWatcherExtendedListener extends NoCopySpan
{
    public void afterTextChanged(View v, Editable s);

    public void onTextChanged(View v, CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count);

    public void beforeTextChanged(View v, CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after);
}
```

2)Created and used EditTextExtended instead of EditText (in my case):

```
public class EditTextExtended extends EditText
{
   private TextWatcherExtendedListener  mListeners = null;

   public EditTextExtended(Context context) 
   {
     super(context);
   }

   public EditTextExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
      super(context, attrs);
   }

   public EditTextExtended(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
   {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
   }

   public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcherExtendedListener watcher) 
   {    
       if (mListeners == null) 
       {
           mListeners = watcher;
       }
   }

   public void removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcherExtendedListener watcher) 
   {
       if (mListeners != null) 
       {
           mListeners = null;        
       }
   }

   void  sendBeforeTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before, int after)
   {
       if (mListeners != null) 
       {
           mListeners.beforeTextChanged(this, text, start, before, after);
       }
   }

   void  sendOnTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int before,int after) 
   {
       if (mListeners != null) 
       {
           mListeners.onTextChanged(this, text, start, before, after);
       }
   }

   void  sendAfterTextChanged(Editable text) 
   {
       if (mListeners != null)
       {
           mListeners.afterTextChanged(this, text);
       }
   }
}
```

3) So, where you need write this code:

```
myEditTextExtended.addTextChangedListener(this) //Let implement TextWatcherExtendedListener methods
```

4)use them:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(View v, CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
   //Tested and works
   //do your stuff  
}


@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(View v, CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
{   
     //not yet tested but it should work    
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(View v, Editable s) 
{
    //not yet tested but it should work 
}
```

Well, let me know what do you think.

Comment: I think this is the most straight forward approach to this issue. +1

Answer (score 12):

**--EDIT--**

If you want to use only afterTextChanged compare editables:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (editable == mEditText1.getEditableText()) {
        // DO STH
    } else if (editable == mEditText2.getEditableText()) {
        // DO STH
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume there will never be the same text in multiple EditText views? Depending on the app that may not be a valid assumption.

Comment: Damn, I'm very sorry, but I am now convinced that I was wrong. I now think that both your original version and the edited version are correct - you are comparing the Java object returned by EditText.getEditableText() with the provided Editable-implementing object, not the texts involved. (In my testing the two objects seem to always be a SpannableStringBuilder object, and Google's documentation for SpannableStringBuilder.equals() says clearly that it compares objects, not the contained text.)

Comment: @RenniePet The first version of my answer was wrong. We shouldn't compare values of the edit texts. Now it works great. I see that my answer should be somewhere on the top of this thread.

Comment: For some reason, this is working in my emulator, but not in the real device, Finally, this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13787221/2263329 Comparing `hashCode()` of the `Editable`.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented it as:

```
edittext1.addTextChangedListener(this);
edittext2.addTextChangedListener(this);
edittext3.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

and:

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    if(edittext1.hasFocus()){
        //text changed for edittext1
    }else if(edittext2.hasFocus()){
        //text changed for edittext2
    }else {
        //text changed for edittext3
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One more way around is to add `OnClickListener` to `EditText` and set a global variable as given below

```
EditText etCurrentEditor;//Global variable

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v instanceof EditText){
            etCurrentEditor=(EditText)v;
        }
    }
```

Use this etCurrentEditor as a reference to currently edited EditText

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (etCurrentEditor.getId()) {
        case R.id.EDITTEXTID:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After try several ways to achieve this, i find the right way using `EditText.isFocused()` to distinguish one to another. For example:

```
    private class OnTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if (edtName.isFocused()) {
            //do something
        } else if (edtEmail.isFocused()) {
            //do something
        } else if (edtContent.isFocused()) {
             //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use multiple instances of a custom `TextWatcher` that store the `TextView`.
(`TextView` is actually the class that has `addTextChangedListener`.)

Similar to the hashCode solution above you can just check if `getText()==s`.
Instead of either storing all your controls or `findViewById` multiple times, you could simply scan the content tree yourself once for the control that has the `CharSequence`.

```
public TextView findTextView(View v, CharSequence s)
{
   TextView tv;
   ViewGroup vg;
   int i, n;

   if (v instanceof TextView)
   {
      tv = (TextView) v;
      if (tv.getText()==s) return(tv);
   }

   else if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
   {
      vg = (ViewGroup) v;
      n = vg.getChildCount();
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)
      {
         tv = findTextView(vg.getChildAt(i), s);
         if (tv!=null) return(tv);
      }
   }

   return(null);
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
   TextView tv=findTextView(findViewById(android.R.id.content), s);
   if (tv==null) return;
   switch(tv.getId())
   {
      case R.id.path:
         break;
      case  R.id.title:
         break;
   }
}
```

Of course you could also use `findTextView` inside `beforeTextChanged` and `onTextChanged`.

Comment: Wonderful solution. It can identify the EditText which I'm editing when used within TextWatcher overridden methods. Can you explain a little bit about how did you get to this solution and used `findViewById(android.R.id.content) to get the editing view?

Comment: `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` is a bit overkill, it gets you the `ViewGroup` which holds your content. It's better to pick the lowest down `ViewGroup` which holds all the text-changing things of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Global One class for all the activities.

**CustomTextWatcher.java**

```
package org.logicbridge.freshclub.customizedItems;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
    public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
        private EditText mEditText;
        Context context;

        public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e, Context context) {
            mEditText = e;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for getting the id of the edit texts. It's not tested but let me know if it works.

```
//setting textWatcher for the editText
textWatcher(owner_name);


public void textWatcher(final EditText editText){

    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

           if(editText.getId()==R.id.your_id){
             //Do something
           }   
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
          if(editText.getId()==R.id.your_id){
          //Do something
          }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
    };

    editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always define `TextWatcher` as a parameter to `addTextChangedListener` method.This way you can have multiple definitions for each edit text.

Answer (score 0):

just compare hash codes of the edittext and string like by using **hashCode()** method

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if (editext.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()){
        type1Total(type1List);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done...

```
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        if (editText1.getText().length() > 0
                && editText2.getText().length() > 0
                && editText3.getText().length() > 0) {

            button.setEnabled(true);
        } else {

            button.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
```

Then just added the TextWatcher to each EditText in the onCreate method & also kept the button setEnabled(false) by default here.

```
button.setEnabled(false); 

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    editText3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, extension function will do the job.
For example, we need to add TextWatcher to `editText1` and `editText2`

Create a extension function like this,

```
 fun EditText.addTextWatcher() {
        this.addTextChangedListener(
                object : TextWatcher {
                    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

                    }

                    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

                    }

                    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                        // you do some common operations here

                        when (this@addTextWatcher) {
                            editText1 -> {
                                // do something for editText1
                            }
                            editText2 -> {
                                // do something for editText2
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        )
    }
```

Then just add the textwatcher to EditTexts like this

```
editText1.addTextWatcher()
editText2.addTextWatcher()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this to have only one `TextWatcher` class to control as many `EditText` either from `Activity` OR `Fragment`

You need to first create a `MultiTextWatcher` class as below

```
class MultiTextWatcher {

    private var callback: TextWatcherWithInstance? = null

    fun setCallback(callback: TextWatcherWithInstance): MultiTextWatcher {
        this.callback = callback
        return this
    }


    fun registerEditText(editText: EditText): MultiTextWatcher {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                callback!!.beforeTextChanged(editText, s, start, count, after)
            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                callback!!.onTextChanged(editText, s, start, before, count)
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                callback!!.afterTextChanged(editText, editable)
            }
        })

        return this
    }

     interface TextWatcherWithInstance {
        fun beforeTextChanged(editText: EditText, s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int)

        fun onTextChanged(editText: EditText, s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int)

        fun afterTextChanged(editText: EditText, editable: Editable)
    }
}
```

Then in your `Activity` or `Fragment`, you need to register as many `EditText` as you want like below, and also I've used [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) to get references of the `XML` views and you can use your ways.

```
 private fun setTextWatchers() {
        MultiTextWatcher()
            .registerEditText(binding.etCompanyAddress)
            .registerEditText(binding.etCompanyIntro)
            .registerEditText(binding.etCompanyName)
            .registerEditText(binding.etCompanyPhone)
            .setCallback(object : MultiTextWatcher.TextWatcherWithInstance {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(editText: EditText, s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(editText: EditText, s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    when (editText) {
                        binding.etCompanyAddress -> {
                            //do your logic here
                        }
                        binding.etCompanyPhone -> {
                            //do your logic here and so on
                        }
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(editText: EditText, editable: Editable) {

                }
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AddOnTextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {

    public interface TextListener {
        void onTextChanged(String value);
    }
    private final TextListener listener;

    public AddOnTextChangeListener(TextListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        listener.onTextChanged(s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}
```

using :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new AddOnTextChangeListener(value -> {

        }));
```