# Get Editable id in afterTextChanged event

Tags: android, events, text

I have an Activity that extends TextWatcher to detect changes in certain EditTexts, so it implements:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
```

My question is: If there are several EditTexts with .addTextChangedListener(this) set, how can I differentiate which one changed given the Editable object in the afterTextChanged procedure?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another option, with fewer anonymous inner classes, would be to simply inspect the currently focused `View`.  **If your application for `TextWatcher` hinges solely on changes made by the user while typing**, then the changes will always occur in the `View` that has current focus.  Calling `getCurrentFocus()` from anywhere inside of an `Activity` or `Window` will return the `View` the user is focused on.  From inside a `TextWatcher`, this will almost assuredly be the specific `EditText` instance.

[SDK Docs Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getCurrentFocus%28%29)

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 2):

There's one method to implement this without creating a `TextWatcher` object for every `EditText`, but I wouldn't use it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // initialization...

    EditText edit1 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    edit1.addTextChangedListener(this);
    EditText edit2 = findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    edit2.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

private static CharSequence makeInitialString(EditText edit) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.setSpan(edit, 0, 0, Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
    return builder;
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    EditText[] edits = s.getSpans( 0, s.length(), EditText.class );
    if (edits.length != 1) {
        // this mustn't happen
    }

    // here's changed EditText
    EditText edit = edits[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see [TextWatcher for more than one EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext)  basically create your own class to handle the listener with a constructor that defines the edittext you are monitoring and pass the edittext you are assigning.