# Android afterTextChanged get EditText tag

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `DialogFragment` containing a `ListView`, with a custom adapter hooked up to the `ListView`. The list displays a bunch of items with an `EditText` for each record to allow the user to enter a quantity.

When any of these quantities change I need to update my array within the adapter, which means linking an `EditText` to a specific element in the array. I do this using the getTag / setTag methods of the `EditText`. Items in the array are unique by two properties:

`LocationID`and
`RefCode`

These are stored in my `TagData` object and set at the point of getView(). I'm attempting to use `EditText.getTag()` once a value has changed, sadly to no avail.

The problem is I can't access the `EditText` in the `afterTextChanged` method.

Here's the `getView()` method of my Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    ItemModel item = (ItemModel) getItem(i);

    TagData tagData = new TagData();
    tagData.setLocationID(item.getLocationID());
    tagData.setRefCode(item.getRefCode());

    EditText txtQuantity = ((EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtQuantity));
    txtQuantity.setTag(tagData);
    txtQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(item.getQtySelected()));

    txtQuantity.addTextChangedListener(this);
    ...
    return view;
}
```

Above I create a `TagData` object and tie it to the `EditText` using `setTag()`. I also hook up an `addTextChangedListener` in the `getView()`. For which the `afterTextChanged` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    EditText editText = (EditText)context.getCurrentFocus(); // This returns the WRONG EditText!?

    // I need this 
    TagData locAndRefcode = (TagData) editText.getTag();
}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5951792/513450) post, `Activity.getCurrentFocus()` should return the `EditText` in question, it doesn't. Instead it returns an `EditText` from the View behind the DialogFragment.

Which leaves me stuck. How can I get access to an `EditText`'s tag from within my afterTextChanged method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would declare your txtQuantity as final and then pass an anonymous new TextWatcher() { ... } into the addTextChangedListener, then you could directly use txtQuantity inside the afterTextChanged(Editable s) method.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Being new to Java this pattern didn't even occur to me! Solved my problem perfectly. Thank you +1

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code

```
private Activity activity;
private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

      @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
          View focView=activity.getCurrentFocus();
          /* if t use EditText.settxt to change text  and the user has no 
           * CurrentFocus  the focView will be null
           */
          if(focView!=null)
          {
         EditText edit= (EditText) focView.findViewById(R.id.item_edit);
         if(edit!=null&&edit.getText().toString().equals(s.toString())){    
         edit.getTag() 
         }
        }
      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
      }

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
              int count) {

      }     

    };
public EditAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list, Activity activity){
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
}
```

Comment: I've since solved this problem using @dev.bmax's solution above, this does also look like it would work however. Thanks for the suggestion I'm sure it might help someone else :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `EditText#getEditableText` method:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    if(editText.getEditableText() == s){
        //
        // Your code
        //
    }

}
```