# when using viewModel pattern how to get the editText text to viewModel

Tags: android

I am Trying to Implement the ViewModel patten using [AndroidViewModel](https://github.com/inloop/AndroidViewModel). I have a some `EditText` in my view. To make the view model responsible to store data i need to get the data to the view model when it is entered.

One way to do it is make a `TextWatcher` for each and every `EditText` and save it to the viewmodel when text is changed. is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, the `ViewModel` handles the `View`s you have created in your view container (that could be a `Fragment` or an `Activity`) without being disturbed by the their life-cycle changes.

To your question: The trick here is that you forward all user interactions on your `View` to the `ViewModel`. So, yes `TextWatcher` will work, but you have to write it on the `ViewModel` and not on your `View`.
Also, `ViewModelHelper` contains methods that you can call from your corresponding view's methods (eg. have Activity.onSaveInstanceState() call

https://github.com/inloop/AndroidViewModel/blob/master/library/src/main/java/eu/inloop/viewmodel/ViewModelHelper.java#L162

I do not think you will need to create a `TextWatcher` for every `EditText`. Can't you create a `TextWatcher` that you will assign to all the `EditText`s and inside one of it's methods identify which `TextView` triggered this and act accordingly?

[Get Editable id in afterTextChanged event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951433/get-editable-id-in-aftertextchanged-event)