# addTextChangedListener get EditText dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have vector of EditTexts that I'm dynamically generating and dynamically adding addTextChangedListeners.

The issue is that the returned Editable on "afterTextChanged" doesn't let me know which EditText this listener is associated with.

Is there a way to call the respective EditText from within the TextWatcher?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating your own TextWatcher but before I put down my untested pseudo-code here, I discovered there's another guy named Sebastian Roth who had already done that.

Check out his answer:
[TextWatcher for more than one EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that option...and thanks for the code too.