# How to Take addTextChangedListener to dynamic Edittexts

Tags: java, android

My Code is: These Take the Custom 3 edittext Than how to adddtextChanged listener to particular foucused Edittext.
the Last edittext focues if delete remaining two and if blank third

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


 TextInputLayout input ;
input = new TextInputLayout(this);

input.setLayoutParams(lparams);

 et = new EditText(this);
 et .setLayoutParams(lparams);
  et .setHint(item.getLabel());
   et .setMinLines(1);

  input.addView(et);
 rl_MainLayout1.addView(input);


   et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


                    if ( et.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                        input.setError(getString(R.string.msg_errorName));
                        requestFocus(et);

                    } else {
                        input.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            });
 }
```

Comment: I suggest creating your own TextWatcher.so see the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext/4283532#4283532)

Comment: what is focused edit text??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/*I solved this By flag variable*/

/*first Declare it*/

int flag=1;

/*on Loop flag++;*/

```
 if(flag==1)
            {
  et1=new EditText(this);
                 }
 else if(flag==2)
            {
  et2=new EditText(this);

                 }

 flag++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `TextChangedListener` to edit text in for loop.

declare global variable named `current` as

```
int current = 0;
```

and change value of that variable on click of `EditText`

```
for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    final int val = i;
    ..
    ..
    et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            current = val;
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

    });
}
```

and read this current value where ever you want.

Comment: Thanks to reply, I used the My owntextWatcger But how  can define which EDITTEXT onTextChanged in threes EDITTEXT in code.

Comment: create interger varibble and set value of that variable to current editing text number...I'll update answer.

Comment: I used it on afterTextChanged

Comment: Please see the question again

Comment: where you declared the edit text..you're initializing it in for loop.