# How to add Text Watcher on multiple Edit text in android?

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

I have an activity which contain two edit text and have a `TextWatcher` in that activity which is implemented separately. I want to make a single class which implements `TextWatcher` and that that `TextWatcher` in that edit text. How can I do that
code:-

```
private TextWatcher getmWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkFieldsForEmpty();
    }
};
private TextWatcher mWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        checkFieldsForEmpty();
    }
};
m_InputMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_mobile);// finding Id of Mobile Number edit text
    m_InputMobile.addTextChangedListener(getmWatcher);
    m_InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);// finding Id of assword editText
    m_InputPassword.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);// defining password edit Tect Input type
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is two ways you can do this.

### First

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              if (m_InputMobile.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
                  checkFieldsForEmpty();
              }
              else if (m_InputPassword.getText().hashCode() == s.hashCode()) {
                  checkFieldsForEmpty();
              }
        }
    };

m_InputMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_mobile);
m_InputMobile.addTextChangedListener(getmWatcher);
m_InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
m_InputPassword.addTextChangedListener(getmWatcher);
```

or make a custome `TextWatcher` class

### Second

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    m_InputMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_mobile);
    m_InputMobile.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(m_InputMobile));
    m_InputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    m_InputPassword.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcher(m_InputPassword));
}

private class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private EditText mEditText;

    public CustomTextWatcher(EditText e) { 
        mEditText = e;
    }

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

   }

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       checkFieldsForEmpty();
   }
}
```

For more details visit [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext) Question.

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

1. Multiple edittext Intialization & Setting TextChangeListener

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<editTexts_ids.length;i++)
   {
       editTexts[i] = (EditText)view.findViewById(editTexts_ids[i]);
       editTexts[i].addTextChangedListener(this);

       textInputLayouts[i]= (TextInputLayout)view.findViewById(textInputLayouts_ids[i]);
       //Log.e("EditText["+i+"]",""+editTexts[i].getId());
   }
   ```
2. In afterTextChanged Method

   ```
   @Override 
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

   for(int i=0;i<editTexts_ids.length;i++) // Disable Error AFter Entered Text
        {//not include Mobile Number Name,S/o, Nominee Edittexts
           if (editTexts[i].getText().hashCode() == editable.hashCode())// Checking
           {
               //Mobile Number VAlidation At Runtime
               if(i==11)
               {
                   if(Utils.Mobile_NumberValidation(editable.toString()))
                   {
                       textInputLayouts[i].setError("");
                       return;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       textInputLayouts[i].setError("Invalid Mobile Number (should start with 7 or 8 or 9) , Length 10 digits");
                       return;
                   }
               }
               if (i == 4) { // for Name
                   if(!Utils.Name_Validation(editable.toString())) {
                       textInputLayouts[4].setError("Invalid Person Name (Special Symbols(@,!,$ .etc), DOT (.) are not allowed)");
                       return;
                   }else
                   {
                       textInputLayouts[4].setError("");
                       return;
                   }
               }
               if (i == 5) { //for S/o,D/o,W/o
                   if(!Utils.Name_Validation(editable.toString())) {
                       textInputLayouts[5].setError("Invalid Person Name (Special Symbols(@,!,$ .etc), DOT (.) are not allowed)");
                       return;
                   }else
                   {
                       textInputLayouts[5].setError("");
                       return;
                   }
               }

               if (i == 9) { //for S/o,D/o,W/o
                   if(!Utils.Name_Validation(editable.toString())) {
                       textInputLayouts[9].setError("Invalid Person Name (Special Symbols(@,!,$ .etc), DOT (.) are not allowed)");
                       return;
                   }else
                   {
                       textInputLayouts[9].setError("");
                       return;
                   }
               }


               if (!editable.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                   textInputLayouts[i].setError("");
                   return;
               }

           }

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: for(int i=0;i<editTexts_ids.length;i++)
        {
            editTexts[i]= (EditText) view.findViewById(editTexts_ids[i]);
            editTexts[i].addTextChangedListener(this);

            textInputLayouts[i]= (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(textInputLayouts_ids[i]);
            //Log.e("EditText["+i+"]",""+editTexts[i].getId());
        }

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `TextWatcher` object and pass it into the `addTextChangeListener` like this :

```
TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
              checkFieldsForEmpty();
        }
    };

    m_InputMobile.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Comment: suppose I have 5 edit text ....then I have to make 5 objects of textWatcher

Comment: set it on second one too like this secondEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

Comment: There's only one object like this. You are passing that one object in different listeners.