# Replace duplicate code of TextWatchers

Tags: java, android

I have a Sign Up screen with bunch of `EditTexts` and each one has a `TextWatcher` so I can "listen" for changes and show or hide errors.

For example :

```
 etFirstName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (etFirstName.getText().length() > 0) {
                hideFirstNameError();
            }
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the code is too bloated with all this code being repeated again and again for each one of my `editTexts`.

So I was just wondering if there is a cleaner way to write it ? Tried to replace with a custom class that extends `TextWatcher`  but then I need to pass as variables to the constructor the `EditText`s and I'm not so sure if this is a good practice : passing to other classes than your `Activities` components that have to do with android ?

Comment: what you doing here    hideFirstNameError();?

Comment: @GaneshPokale  `tilFirstname.setError(null);
        tilFirstname.setErrorEnabled(false);` I hide the error from the corresponding `TextInputLayout` of the editText field.

Comment: which code is repeated?

Comment: @TimCastelijns the code block I have posted above. I'm doing the same for every `EditText`.

Comment: You may find your solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext

Comment: I don't believe you are calling hideFirstNameError for every edittext

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class:

```
public class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        //empty
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //empty
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //empty
    }
}
```

And pass it instead of `new TextWatcher()`.