# Move text to next Edittext in TableRow

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have created one TableLayout in which I am dynamically adding 50 Rows with EditText. I set the text limit for a single edit text such that if the 1st row reaches to limit, cursor of EditText moves to the next row dynamically. How can I do that? Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you need edittext.requestFocus();?

Comment: but edittext is dynamic what ever edit text is clicked and reached to limit automatically go to the next edittext

Comment: Well then you still have to get the next edit text. When creating the edit texts dynamically. give them id's with increasing numbers so you can access them afterwards.

Comment: i think  you have to use textwatcher in that you can check your edittext limit and make logic there

Comment: @cherry-wave means u saying need to store all ids in array when its clicked and reached to limit move to foucs to next edittext

Comment: @VishalThakkar I have 50 edittext for all need to create textwatcher , which is not proper way to do

Comment: You can add one TextWatcher for all. You get the editText in the event, can test if the limit is reached, and then get set focus to the next editText (by reading out the id of the current edit text and increasing the number)

Comment: Do you have 1 textview with 50 rows or 50 textviews with 1 row ?

Comment: @MarkB  1 TabelRow with 1 EditView that is added 50 times

Comment: @cherry-wave okay Let me check that way, but how to add one TextWatcher for all

Comment: OK it seems TextWatcher doesn't get the actual EditText so you have to do a little twist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext

Comment: @pcpriyanka if you dont want create new instance of text watcher then you can try like this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext

Comment: I would suggest @Vishal's first link, the other one we both posted isn't suitable for dynamic editTexts. I know, with this solution you have to create multiple TextWatchers, but this may be the only way.

Comment: @cherry-wave vishal thanks let me try one

Comment: @VishalThakkar As you suggested I set Textwatcher for all EditText now how to setFocus for next editText

Comment: on which condition you want to set focus to next  edittext

Comment: text limit for 25

Comment: oh.then in just make condition like if charseq.length() >25 then focus to next edit text

Comment: @VishalThakkar thanks ! its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126228/discussion-between-pcpriyanka-and-vishal-thakkar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found solution

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        EditText dueAmountText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        dueAmountText.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 5.0f));
        dueAmountText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        dueAmountText.setTextSize(26f);
        dueAmountText.setMaxLines(1);
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(TextLength);
        dueAmountText.setFilters(FilterArray);


        Drawable drawable = dueAmountText.getBackground(); // get current EditText drawable
        drawable.setColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

        dueAmountText.setBackground(drawable); // set the new drawable to EditText

        allwtEditTextList.add(dueAmountText);
        newRow.addView(dueAmountText);
        tableLayout.addView(newRow);
    }
    for (int z = 0; z < allwtEditTextList.size(); z++) {
        final int pos = z;
        allwtEditTextList.get(z).addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (s.length() >= TextLength) {
                    Log.e("TextCount", pos + "--" + allwtEditTextList.size());

                    if (pos < (allwtEditTextList.size() - 1)) {
                        EditText editText = allwtEditTextList.get(pos + 1);
                        editText.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Need getTag() here
                allwtEditTextList.get(pos).getTag();
            }
        });
    }



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```