# Value Of EditText In android Get changed after Typing to initial value

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

Value is automatically changed after user started typing in `EditText`.Value is automatically changed with initial value.
Please Help me what is causing this issue

**This layout is USed for adapter layout the complete layout file and adapter code is given below here is EditTextbox part that is causing issue**

```
               <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">
              <TextView
                    style="@style/booking_heading"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Enter Amount" />
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:editable="true"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="#fff"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:text="00"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/booking_price" />
               </LinearLayout>
```

### Code Of My Adapter class is

```
package com.visionprecis.vikrant;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.visionprecis.vikrant.DriverService.Booking;
import com.visionprecis.vikrant.LocationProvider.TrackingActivity;
import com.visionprecis.vikrant.StaticData.StaticInfo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class BookingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    ArrayList<Booking> bookingArrayList;
    Context context;
    public BookingArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource,ArrayList<Booking> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context=context;
        this.bookingArrayList=objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position,  View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_booking_layout,null);

        final Booking booking=bookingArrayList.get(position);

        TextView orgin=view.findViewById(R.id.booking_origin);
        TextView destination=view.findViewById(R.id.booking_destination);
        TextView status=view.findViewById(R.id.booking_status);
        final EditText price=view.findViewById(R.id.booking_price);
        Button trackbtn=view.findViewById(R.id.booking_track_btn);
        Button cancel=view.findViewById(R.id.booking_cancel);
        Button confirm=view.findViewById(R.id.booking_confirm);
        orgin.setText(booking.getOrigin().getAdress());
        destination.setText(booking.getDestination().getAdress());
        status.setText(booking.getStatus());
        price.setText(booking.getPrice());
        if(booking.getStatus().equals(StaticInfo.RIDE_REQUESTED)){
            confirm.setText("Send Amount");
            confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   sendbidamound(booking,price.getText().toString());
                    Log.i(StaticInfo.TAG,"Price kis "+price.getText());
                }
            });
        }else if(booking.getStatus().equals(StaticInfo.RIDE_BID_PROVIDED)){
        //   confirm.setText("Confirmed");
            confirm.setText("Send Amount");
            confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   sendbidamound(booking,price.getText().toString());
                    Log.i(StaticInfo.TAG,"Price kis "+price.getText());

                }
            });


        }

            trackbtn.setEnabled(true);
           trackbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   trackuser(booking.getUserid());
               }
           });

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                oncancelpressed(booking);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void trackuser(String userid) {
       Intent intent=new Intent(context,TrackingActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("userid",userid);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void oncancelpressed(Booking booking) {

        DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(StaticInfo.USER_BOOKING_REQUEST_TABLE)
                .child(booking.getUserid())
                .child(booking.getBookingid());
        reference.child("status").setValue(StaticInfo.RIDE_CANCELED).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
           Toast.makeText(context,"Booking caceled Succcessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendbidamound(final Booking booking, final String price) {
        if(validateprice()){
            DatabaseReference userreference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(StaticInfo.USER_BOOKING_REQUEST_TABLE)
                    .child(booking.getUserid())
                    .child(booking.getBookingid());
            HashMap<String,Object> updatevalue=new HashMap<>();

            updatevalue.put("status",StaticInfo.RIDE_BID_PROVIDED);
            updatevalue.put("price",price);

            userreference.updateChildren(updatevalue).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                    DatabaseReference driverreference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(StaticInfo.DRIVER_BOOKING_REQUEST_TABLE)
                            .child(booking.getDriverid())
                            .child(booking.getBookingid());
                    HashMap<String,Object> updatechild=new HashMap<>();
                    updatechild.put("status",StaticInfo.RIDE_BID_PROVIDED);
                    updatechild.put("price",price);
                    driverreference.updateChildren(updatechild).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Bid amount Placed Succcesfully Awaiting User Confirmation And You Will Be Notified back",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            context.startActivity(new Intent(context,MainActivity.class));
                        }
                    });

                }
            });


        }

    }

    private boolean validateprice() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

### **Complete Layout Of The adapter is**

```
        <!-- Begning Of child Layout  horizental-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                style="@style/booking_heading"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Origin" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/booking_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/booking_origin"
                android:text="Shimla Himachal Pradesh India" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Of child Layout  horizental-->




        <!-- Begning Of child Layout  horizental-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                style="@style/booking_heading"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Destination" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/booking_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/booking_destination"
                android:text="Shimla Himachal Pradesh India" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Of child Layout  horizental-->



        <!-- Begning Of child Layout  horizental-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                style="@style/booking_heading"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Ride Status" />

            <TextView
                style="@style/booking_value"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/booking_status"
                android:text=" " />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Of child Layout  horizental-->


        <!-- Begning Of child Layout  horizental-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <TextView
                style="@style/booking_heading"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Enter Amount" />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:editable="true"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/booking_price" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- End Of child Layout  horizental-->
        <!-- Begning Of child Layout  horizental-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <Button
                style="@style/booking_heading"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#273e70"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/booking_cancel"/>

            <Button
                style="@style/booking_heading"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#273e70"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="Confirm"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:id="@+id/booking_confirm" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End Of child Layout  horizental-->
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Track User"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:id="@+id/booking_track_btn"
    />


    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- End  Of main Layout  vertical-->
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### The Activity layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RequestedRidesListActivity">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/booking_list_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Layout of the File is[image]

Comment: show your activity code where you are using this edittext

Comment: Well iam using a long code where this layout is used for a adpater layout and then adapter is set To List View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set textwatcher to your edit text ?

Comment: No i havn'y Done something like that . Although You can i have look at my adapter where iam setting value

Comment: why you do this price.setText(booking.getPrice()); if you set your edit text can be edited ? it's pointless. Can you tell me what do you want to achieve ? do you want to catch user input in edit text or you want to set value to your edit text ??

Comment: I added the price that is bid by other user . here i want is that if Current Driver(User using this app) can change the amount and then this price will be send back to user

Comment: Okay then you should put textwatcher to your edit text to detect your user input. This is the link how to do it  (look in the answer) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4283062/textwatcher-for-more-than-one-edittext

Comment: Well Problem Solved Textwatxher saved my day  thankyou